# TypeError when passing a bash variable into a python script

Tags: python, bash, error-handling

When I run the bash program that calls the python script below I get this error: `line 12, in roundup return int(int(math.ceil(x / 1000)) * (10**3)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`
When the python script is run by itself there are no issues or errors. I checked to make sure that the bash variable was not a float and it is not on both programs. I am not sure how to fix this. I tried `int(int(math.ceil(x / 1000)) * (10****3))` and `int(math.ceil(x / 1000)) * (10**3)`

```
import math
import os

pdiv=os.environ["div"]
print(pdiv)
#pdiv=931573 in both the bash srcipt that is calling this python script and the python script
divi=str(pdiv)
divide=len(divi)


if divide >= 4 and divide < 7:
    def roundup(x):
        return int(int(math.ceil(x / 1000)) * (10**3))
    z=roundup(pdiv)
    array = [int(x) for x in str(z)]
    if z == 4: 
       byte=str(array[0]) +'k'
        
        
    elif z == 5:
        byte=str(array[0]) + str(array[1]) + 'k'
        
    elif divide == 6:
        byte=str(array[0]) + str(array[1]) + str(array[2]) + 'k'
        

elif divide >= 7 and divide < 10:
    def roundup(x):
        return int(int(math.ceil(x / 1000000)) * (10**6))
    z=roundup(pdiv)
    array = [int(x) for x in str(z)]
    if divide == 7:
        byte=str(array[0]) +'m'
        
    elif divide == 8:
        #byte=print(array[0], end="");print(array[1], end="");print('m')
        byte=str(array[0]) + str(array[1]) + 'm'
        
    elif divide == 9:
        byte=str(array[0]) + str(array[1]) + str(array[2]) + 'm'
        
    
file = open("Bytes.txt", "w")
file.write(byte)
file.close
```

Comment: The values from `os.environ[...]` are always strings. Convert `pdiv` to `int` or `float`.

Comment: Don't define functions inside `if` blocks, define them globally. If you need different denominators and exponents, make them function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The error is from the expression: `x / 1000`. In your script, `x` is a string, which you get from an environment variable. When you attempt to divide a string by an int, you get that error. To fix, you need to convert the string into a number:

```py
def roundup(x):
    x = int(x)
    return int(int(math.ceil(x / 1000)) * (10**3))
```